# exclude value with in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I've been trying to figure out how to exclude a value from an array generated by ng-options using filters with no luck.

The array generated by the snippet below generates the following array `["publicExtra","public","private"]` I want to exclude "public" from the options. Thanks in advance.

```
<select ng-model="elb_instance.use_vpc"
                    ng-options="('Subnet: ' + type) for type in elb_instance.vpc_names_with_subnet_types_for_elb[elb_instance.vpc_name]"
                    ng-disabled="!elb_instance['new_record?']"
                    ng-show="elb_instance.vpc_name"
                    id="use_vpc"
                    class="input-medium">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) and using `!` before search string to negate the predicate like:

```
ng-options="('Subnet: ' + type) for type in types | filter: '!public'">
```

But note that this ignores both `public` & `publicExtra` as basic filter does not do exact match. For that, we will also need to pass `true` for the `comparator` like:

```
ng-options="('Subnet: ' + type) for type in types | filter: '!public' : true">
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = "";
  $scope.types = ["publicExtra","public","private"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selected" 
      ng-options="('Subnet: ' + type) for type in types | filter: '!public' : true">
    </select>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, palash. This worked. No need to add the extra code in the controller.

ng-options="('Subnet: ' + type) for type in types | filter: '!public' : true">

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth. I'm realizing that now I have another issue. That filter needs to be applied if a condition is true. so as an example  if (elb_vm.elbInstances[index]['new_record?']) then apply filter otherwise do not.

Comment: Yes, please create a sperate question for this, so that there is a separation of concern and future users can get specific answers for a specific issue while searching SO.